# Does EF Core Database-First have migrations?

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-database-first

I'm wondering if there's a standard (or even defacto) way of handing migrations when using EF Core database-first.

[The docs for migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#create-a-migration) seem to make an assumption that you're going code-first and [the docs for reverse engineering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding) basically say "you can change the model once its generated, but you'll lose your changes if you generate it again". Furthermore, I've come across many code-first tutorials that cover migrations, but database-first ones just stop after the initial scaffolding.

It would make sense if the answer is just that code-first has better support for handling migrations, but I've never seen any such claim/complaint about that limitation when people talk about the differences which makes me think it's just as likely that I'm just missing something.